# Keeping a file open for writing when in a class or function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write code that writes a classes variables to a .csv file whenever an object of that class is created. My current code is:

```
class planet():
def __init__(self, constant, parent, angle, tier):
    global csv_file
    self.writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = ["Name", "Constant", "Height", "Period", "Tier", "Parent", "Size"])
    self.writer.writerow({"Name": "Bob", "Constant": str(self.constant), "Height": str(self.height), "Period": str(self.period), "Tier": str(self.tier), "Parent": "Jeff", "Size": str(self.size)})
```

PS(sorry for the formatting, I couldn't get the wrapping to look nice)

The other lines in the init() function have been removed for clarity as they don't affect this part of my code. Earlier in the code I called this function to open my .csv file:

```
def export():
global csv_file
with open('Solar System.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = ["Name", "Constant", "Height", "Period", "Tier", "Parent", "Size"])
    writer.writeheader()
```

When I tried this code I got this error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. I understand this is because I am trying to write to a closed file. To remedy this I tried to put the `with open()` statement at the top of my `__init__()` but this didn't work as whenever the class got called it erased the previous row and wrote it with its own data.

To clarify my questions are:

1. How can this be sorted such that every time the class constructor is used its variables get added to a row in `Solar System.csv` (that is the desired output)
2. I don't mind if this is done with another module, I looked into pandas but thought that would be harder but am open to any suggestions using this.
3. If this cant be done when the constructor is used and instead has to be done outside the class or later on how could I achieve that.

Thanks, BTW I really struggle with syntax so would you lease be able to explain any answer in a bit of depth that would really help my understanding.

EDIT1: I am unsure of what other bits of code would help people answer this question, so I am just going to post all my code and use some comments to denote areas of interest.

```
    import math, random, pygame, time, sys, csv
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
canvasw = 1366
canvash = 768
window = pygame.display.set_mode((canvasw, canvash), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
planetquantity = 0
planetcolour = (150, 150, 150)
showtracers = False

def export():
    global csv_file
    with open('Solar System.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = ["Name", "Constant", "Height", "Period", "Tier", "Parent", "Size"])
        writer.writeheader()
        
class planet():
    def __init__(self, constant, parent, angle, tier):
        global csv_file ## this is the main area where the problem is, the rest of the code works as intended.
        self.childlist = []
        self.constant = constant
        self.parent = parent
        self.angle = angle
        self.pos = (0, 0)
        self.tier = tier
        self.height = random.randint(50, 100) * self.parent.constant / self.tier
        self.period = math.sqrt((self.height ** 3) * self.parent.constant)
        self.size = int((self.constant / (self.tier / 1.0)) * 10)
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = ["Name", "Constant", "Height", "Period", "Tier", "Parent", "Size"])
        self.writer.writerow({"Name": "Bob", "Constant": str(self.constant), "Height": str(self.height), "Period": str(self.period), "Tier": str(self.tier), "Parent": "Jeff", "Size": str(self.size)})
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)

    def generatemoons(self, maxtier):
        global planetquantity
        if self.tier != maxtier:
            for i in range(0, random.randint(0, 5)):
                tempconstant = self.constant  / random.uniform(1.0, 3.0)
                tempangle= random.randint(0, 360)
                temptier = self.tier + 1
                self.childlist.append(planet(tempconstant, self, tempangle, temptier))
                planetquantity += 1
                self.childlist[i].generatemoons(maxtier)

    def draw(self):
        if len(self.childlist) > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(self.childlist)):
                pygame.draw.circle(window, planetcolour, self.childlist[i].pos, self.childlist[i].size)
                if showtracers == True:
                    pygame.draw.line(window, planetcolour, self.pos, self.childlist[i].pos, 1)
                self.childlist[i].draw()

    def updatemoons(self):
        if len(self.childlist) > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(self.childlist)):            
                self.childlist[i].angle += (365 / self.childlist[i].period)
                x, y = self.pos
                height = self.childlist[i].height
                newx = int(x + math.sin(math.radians(self.childlist[i].angle)) * height)
                newy = int(y + math.cos(math.radians(self.childlist[i].angle)) * height)
                self.childlist[i].pos = (newx, newy)
                self.childlist[i].updatemoons()
class sun():
    def __init__(self, constant, tier):
        self.constant = constant
        self.tier = tier
        self.childlist = []
        self.pos = (int(canvasw / 2), int(canvash / 2))
        self.size = 40

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)

    def generatemoons(self):
        global planetquantity
        if self.tier > 0:
            for i in range(0, random.randint(0, 5)):
                tempconstant = self.constant  / random.uniform(1.0, 3.0)
                tempangle= random.randint(0, 360)
                temptier = 1
                self.childlist.append(planet(tempconstant, self, tempangle, temptier))
                planetquantity += 1
                self.childlist[i].generatemoons(self.tier)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, planetcolour, self.pos, self.size)
        for i in range(0, len(self.childlist)):
            pygame.draw.circle(window, planetcolour, self.childlist[i].pos, self.childlist[i].size)
            if showtracers == True:
                pygame.draw.line(window, planetcolour, self.pos, self.childlist[i].pos, 1)
            self.childlist[i].draw()    

    def updatemoons(self):
        if len(self.childlist) > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(self.childlist)):            
                self.childlist[i].angle += (365 / self.childlist[i].period)
                x, y = self.pos
                height = self.childlist[i].height
                newx = int(x + math.sin(math.radians(self.childlist[i].angle)) * height)
                newy = int(y + math.cos(math.radians(self.childlist[i].angle)) * height)
                self.childlist[i].pos = (newx, newy)
                self.childlist[i].updatemoons()
export() ## Here I called export before anything else thinging that if I opened my file as the first thing it would stay open for when class planets start getting added.
sun = sun(5.5, 1)
sun.generatemoons()
for i in range(0, len(sun.childlist)):
    print(sun.childlist[i])
print(planetquantity)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
##    start = time.time()
    sun.updatemoons()
    sun.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
    window.fill((0, 0 , 0))
##    end = time.time()
##    print(end - start)
```

Comment: Share the "big picture" with us. What are the main classes? why the csv file is global, etc. Share more code as well. As for now the question is not clear.

Comment: `with open(...) as csv_file` closes the open file at the end of the `with` block. You can't use `with` in this situation. Instead do `csv_file = open(...)` as your program starts and be very sure to call `close()` on it as your program ends, even if it crashes.

Comment: @BoarGules, my program is technically infinite as I have no intention of breaking out of the while True loop, could I use `close()` once the class constructor has finished being used?

Comment: Not if methods of your class need the file to be still open.

Comment: @BoarGules, thank you, your solution worked, BTW, do you know why there is a blank .csv row between every entry?

Comment: From the docs on csv.writer(): "If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''` " .

Comment: @BoarGules, once again thanks